# Xquery- flat XML to nested XML

Tags: xml, xquery

I've got a flat XML file that looks something like this:

```
<Data>
   <DataType1>1</DataType1>
   <DataType2>2</DataType2>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
   <DataType1>1</DataType1>
   <DataType2>2</DataType2>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
</Data>
```

I want to be able to nest this using Xquery, to look like this:

```
 <Data>
       <DataType1>1
          <DataType2>2
             <DataType3>3
                <DataType4>4</DataType4>
             </DataType3>
          </DataType2>
             <DataType3>3
                <DataType4>4</DataType4>
            </DataType3>
      </DataType1>
       <DataType1>1
          <DataType2>2
             <DataType3>3
                <DataType4>4</DataType4>
             </DataType3>          
         </DataType2>
      </DataType1>
 </Data>
```

I basically want to nest based on order, so any "2" will be nested under the previous "1" node, and so on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the placement of the closing tag for the first DataType2 element in your example output is a typo, and that it should actually occur *after* the following DataType3.

The following works for me in eXist-db

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:getLevel($n) as xs:integer {
    xs:integer(substring-after($n/local-name(), 'DataType'))
};

declare function local:buildHierarchy($seq) {
    if (empty($seq)) then ()
    else
    let $lvl := local:getLevel($seq[1]),
        $until := (
            for $el at $p in $seq
            where $p gt 1 and local:getLevel($el) le $lvl
            return $p
            ,
            count($seq) + 1
        )[1]
    return (
        element { node-name($seq[1]) } {
            $seq[1]/text(),
            local:buildHierarchy(subsequence($seq, 2, $until - 2))
        },
        local:buildHierarchy(subsequence($seq, $until))
    )
};

let $data := <Data>
   <DataType1>1</DataType1>
   <DataType2>2</DataType2>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
   <DataType1>1</DataType1>
   <DataType2>2</DataType2>
   <DataType3>3</DataType3>
   <DataType4>4</DataType4>
</Data>
return
    <Data>{local:buildHierarchy($data/*)}</Data>
```

`local:getLevel()` determines the nesting priority of your elements (in this case, simply by returning the number in the element name). An element with a higher nesting priority than its preceding sibling will be nested inside it.

`local:buildHierarchy()` does the real work of building the new structure.  It basically chunks its input sequence into three parts: (1) the first item, (2) all contiguous following items with a higher nesting priority, and (3) the first equal or lower priority item and all those following. It makes a copy of (1) and uses recursion to nest (2) inside that copy, then recurses on (3) to create the next same-level siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function for unnesting the data. I added a "debug attribute" for testing purpose, feel free to remove it (and the line with the matching comment).

```
declare function local:unflatten($xs as node()*) {
  for $x in $xs
  return
    let $next := ($x/following-sibling::*[number(text()) <= number($x/text())])[1]
    return
      element { concat("DataType", $x/text()) } {
        attribute id { $x/@id }, (: remove debug output here :)
        $x/text(),
        "&#10;", (: Print newline character :)
        local:unflatten($x/following-sibling::*[
              (empty($next) or . << $next)
            and
              number(text()) = $x/text() + 1
          ]
        )
      }
};

let $xml := <Data>
   <DataType1 id="1">1</DataType1>
   <DataType2 id="2">2</DataType2>
   <DataType3 id="3">3</DataType3>
   <DataType4 id="4">4</DataType4>
   <DataType3 id="5">3</DataType3>
   <DataType4 id="6">4</DataType4>
   <DataType1 id="7">1</DataType1>
   <DataType2 id="8">2</DataType2>
   <DataType3 id="9">3</DataType3>
   <DataType4 id="10">4</DataType4>
</Data>

return element Data { local:unflatten($xml/*[text()=1]) }
```